# Matrix multiplication with random numbers larger than 1000

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to get two matrices with randomly generated numbers to multiply together but i keep getting segmentation fault and idk how to allocate the memory properly.

any help with this would be great

//here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
srand (1023);
int a[1000][1000], b[1000][1000], mult[1000][1000], r1, c1, r2, c2, i, j, k;
cout << "Enter rows and columns for first matrix: ";
cin >> r1 >> c1;
cout << "Enter rows and columns for second matrix: ";
cin >> r2 >> c2;

while (c1!=r2)
{
   cout << "Error! column of first matrix not equal to row of second.";

}

cout << endl << endl;
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c1; ++j)
{
    cout<<"mult["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: "<<rand()%9+1<<" "; //random matrix 1
}

cout << endl<< endl;
for(i=0; i<r2; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
{
    cout<<"mult["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: "<<rand()%9+1<<" "; //random matrix 2
}

for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
{
   mult[i][j]=rand()%9+1;
}


for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
for(k=0; k<c1; ++k)
{
    mult[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j]; //matrix multiplication
}

cout << endl << "Output Matrix: " << endl;
clock_t begin = clock();
for(i=0; i<r1; ++i)
for(j=0; j<c2; ++j)
    cout << " " << mult[i][j];
    if(j==c2)
        cout << endl;
clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end-begin)*100;
    cout<<"Elapsed Time: "<<elapsed_secs<<" milliseconds\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `int`, to store large numbers.

Comment: You're not intialising the elements of arrays `a` and `b` at all.  Accessing their elements, even with valid indices, gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: then how would you initialize them

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create more than 11 MB in your current stack.

> array[1000][1000] = 4 * 1000 * 1000 bytes = 4000000

You are creating in total 12000000 bytes for 3 arrays alone.

Try reducing the size of the array (or) get the size of the matrix and try to create the array in heap using new.

Check your stack size, it should be 8 MB

```
ulimit -a | grep stack
```

This is how you do for heap since you want 1000 to 5000

```
   int** a = new int*[r1];
   for(int i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
   {
      a[i] = new int[c1];
   }

   a[0][0] = 10;

   std::cout << a[0][0] << std::endl;

   // Delete all the columns  
   for(int i = 0; i < r1; ++i)
     delete[] a[i];

   delete []a ;
```

Also make sure you add values to a[][] and b[][], now you just do cout and print the values in the first 2 for loops and I suppose those should be in a[][] and b[][]

Comment: i need the array to be anywhere from 1000 to 5000

Comment: You can then create in heap. Use new and delete[] operators to create and delete array in heap

Comment: ive tried doing that we a[][], b[][], mult[][] and it wouldnt work

Comment: this is in ubuntu by the way

Comment: @nathan Edited the answer with example on how to create a 2 d array in heap

Comment: This code deallocates the `int** a = new int*[r1];` but not the `a[i] = new int[c1];` which is actually most of the allocated memory. Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead.

Comment: @MarianSpanik yeah! bug, let me fix it